# Breakout in jquery to plain javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, breakout

I created the breakout game in jquery with help of a handy tutorial.
My professor now tells me it must be in plain javascript and I am having trouble converting to plain javascript.

The fiddle is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Kinetic915/9bLEk/6/

the code loads properly. I am finding a problem changing the code that renders the ball.
It works with jquery here:

```
Cir = $('#canvas')[0].getContext("2d");

Cir.beginPath();
Cir.arc(x, y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
Cir.closePath();
Cir.fill();
```

The lower works by itself in a separate fiddle, but NOT inside of the project.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var Cir = canvas.getContext("2d");

Cir.beginPath();
Cir.arc(x, y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
Cir.closePath();
Cir.fill();
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: what is this game supposed to do? all i see is a ball drop

Comment: It will drop off the paddle.  Click on the screen where the game is located and use the arrow keys to move the paddle.  Obviously that will illustrate it works currently using jquery.  I am attempting to achieve the same game using javascript with your help!

Comment: it's currently not working with jQuery either

Comment: is that fiddle not rendering correctly?  Ive tried it from several computer successfully.  http://jsfiddle.net/Kinetic915/B77UB/1/

Comment: Ive changed several lines to use plain javascript but cannot figure out how to make the rendering of the ball work without using jquery and also move the paddle according to key press without jquery.

Comment: the ball drops then nothing

Comment: if it does not hit the paddle and ends in the gutter the animation will stop.  The paddle is moved with the arrow keys

Comment: most updated: http://jsfiddle.net/Kinetic915/nVctR/

Comment: most is now in javascript except paddle movement as well as rendering of the circle (above) which I cannot ifgure out

Comment: still now working for me using chrome

Comment: very strange can you post a pic or video? just tried with chrome working perfect

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/Kinetic915/nVctR/show

Comment: i think the problem is not having focus on the area the code is rendering?  in order to move the paddle you have to click on the render area.

Comment: got it working - can you add the code that isn't specifically working guess I'm confused because it looks fine - when using canvas most of it is pure js anyway

Comment: have you tried addEventListener

Comment: something like canvas.addEventListener('keydown', function (evt) { 
    if (evt.keyCode == 39) rightpress = false;
}, false);

Comment: Ohh gotcha,  thats what I was thinking as far as the keydown goes but I didnt know the exact syntax.  Sure!  I will add the code that makes it fail.  Thank you for your help!  I will highlight it in the project.

Comment: well.... got it working with exactly I thought would make it work.  didn't work before.  Murphy's law I suppose.  The only part now in jquery is     $(document).keydown(Keypress);
     $(document).keyup(Keyoff); what is the javascript equivalent?

Comment: got working with window.onkeydown = Keypress;
window.onkeyup = Keyoff;